# How to pass CSV file as an argument to python file

Tags: python

I am trying to supply csv file as an argument in python file, 
Here, I want to pass features.csv file as an argument. 
Any thoughts how to make it?

```
def read_csv_file():
with open(r'features.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
    checker = lambda i: bool(i and i.strip())
    raw_file = csv.reader(csvFile)
    header = next(raw_file)
    folders = next(
        {
            header[0]: [row[0]],
            'Feature Name': list(filter(checker, row[:1])),
            'Child folder': list(filter(checker, row[1:]))
        } for row in raw_file
    )
    raw_folder_list = list(folders.values())
    folder_list = sum(raw_folder_list, [])
    return folder_list
```

Comment: `def read_csv_file(file_name):` And method call should be like `read_csv_file('features.csv')`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to make filename a command line argument so that, you can reuse this code to open all similar csv files.

In that case, you can use [argparse](https://pymotw.com/2/argparse/)

or, simply

```
>> python read_csv.py filename.csv
```

In read_csv.py

```
import sys
first_arg = sys.argv[1]
print(first_arg)
# filename.csv
```

I would recommend using argparse since it is more robust.

Answer (score 1):

```
def read_csv_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as csvFile:
        checker = lambda i: bool(i and i.strip())
        raw_file = csv.reader(csvFile)
        header = next(raw_file)
        folders = next(
        {
            header[0]: [row[0]],
            'Feature Name': list(filter(checker, row[:1])),
            'Child folder': list(filter(checker, row[1:]))
        } for row in raw_file
        )
        raw_folder_list = list(folders.values())
        folder_list = sum(raw_folder_list, [])
        return folder_list
```

call function with file name like:  read_csv_file('features.csv')

Comment: how come will it still be an argument?

Comment: also, when I write like this: read_csv_file('features.csv') it says, formal parameter name expected

Comment: Your code will read features.csv file every time but what I provided you just need to call function with argument as file name in it

Comment: @Vashdev thats correct, illtech Please provide the error and the code you so that we can help you better.

Comment: @iltech, this error occurs when you try to pass a string as parameter to a function in the function header, without a parameter name , do a function call from outside the function.